# print format error in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, printing, format

I am trying to format a print statement `print("{:, <13d}".format(int(information[i])), end="")` where the `int(information[i])` is a number in the millions.  However, I get the `builtins.ValueError: Invalid conversion specification`  error.

The only way I can get the comma separation is without spacing like this: `{:,}`

Without using `locale` and stuff, is there anyway to fix this?

Update: When I do `print("{:,<13d}".format(int(information[i])), end="")`, It prints as the `number,,,,,,'next value'` instead of `x,xxx,xxx   'next value'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> print("{:<13,d}".format(int(information[i])), end="")
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes much more sense.  Is that just syntax or is there reasoning behind the , going after the spacing? I never learned the comma trick with spacing, which is why I assumed it went were I had it.

Comment: I don't think spaces are allowed at all inside the replacement field braces https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings